# Make a line chart using the ui.Chart.array.values function (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a way to make a line chart with the `ui.Chart.array.values` function? When I try to set the chart type using `.setChartType('LineChart')`, it shows only points and has a weird scale on the h-axis.

Additionally, I want to include another band for a different year, say `VIIRS2019` to show two plots on the same chart and do a visual comparison, can I just add the 'avg_rad' from that other image into my `VIIRS2014`?

```
// CITY AND TOWNS SHAPEFILES
var point = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    ee.Geometry.Point([-118.243683, 34.052235]);
var cities = ee.FeatureCollection("users/j9herrer/USACities2");

var mycity = cities.filterBounds(point);
//var la = ee.Geometry.Point([-118.243683, 34.052235]);
mycity = mycity.filterBounds(point);
var city_outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: mycity,
  width: 2
});

Map.addLayer(mycity);

var latLon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('longitude');

// TRANSECT 
var geom_city = mycity.geometry();

var boundingbox=geom_city.bounds();
var coords = boundingbox.coordinates().get(0); 
//for whatever reason .coordinates returns a list with one element which is the list we want, hence .get(0)
coords = ee.List(coords);
var NW = coords.get(1);
var SE = coords.get(3);
var mydiagonal = ee.Geometry.LineString([NW,SE]);
Map.addLayer(mydiagonal);
print (mydiagonal, "Transect");

// VIIRS DATA
var VIIRS = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG");
VIIRS = VIIRS.select('avg_rad');

var VIIRS2014 = VIIRS.filterDate('2014-1-1','2015-1-1').mean().addBands(latLon);
var VIIRS2019 = VIIRS.filterDate('2019-1-1','2020-1-1').mean().addBands(latLon);

var VIIR2014List = VIIRS2014.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: mydiagonal,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print (VIIR2014List, "VIIRS 2014, List");

var lon = ee.List(VIIR2014List.get('longitude'));
var avgRad = ee.List(VIIR2014List.get('avg_rad'));
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(avgRad, 0, lon ).setChartType('LineChart');


print(chart);
```

Comment: You have two questions here. For the benefit of those searching for QA and for people answering, I recommend asking the second question in a separate post and removing it from this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some unknown reasons, `ui.Chart.array.values` does not support `LineChart`. If you really want a line chart from your data, you can use `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature` instead. The example code below could be added to the end of your code.

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List.sequence(0, lon.size().subtract(1)).map(function(index) {
  return ee.Feature(null, { avgRad: avgRad.get(index), lon: lon.get(index)})
}))
print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(fc.sort('lon'), 'lon', 'avgRad'))
```

The code just creates a Feature Collection `fc` where each feature has two properties `avgRad` and `lon`. Then it draws a chart using `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature`. The `sort` function is to make sure longitude is sorted, otherwise you'll get a weird line that crosses its own.

Comment: Just to note, you can make line charts directly from the `ui.Chart.array.values()` function - see my answer.

Comment: Yeah, had the same issue of `ui.Chart.array.values` not supporting line-chart type

Answer (score 3):

You can make area line charts and line charts. Add the following code to the end of your script.

- It is important to sort the x-y observations by x (longitude in your case).
- Manually set the `hAxis` range using the `viewWindow` `min` and `max` parameters.
- To get a line chart, you need to hide the points and show the line using the `pointSize` and `lineSize` properties.

```js
// Sort the observations according to longitude.
var lonSorted = lon.sort(lon);
var avgRad = avgRad.sort(lon);

// Make an area line chart. 
var areaChart = ui.Chart.array.values(avgRad, 0, lonSorted)
  .setChartType('AreaChart')
  .setOptions({
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Longitude',
      viewWindow: {min: -118.870, max: -117.487},
    },
    vAxis: {title: 'VIIRS ???'},
    legend: {position: 'none'}
  });
print(areaChart);

// Make a line chart.
var lineChart = ui.Chart.array.values(avgRad, 0, lonSorted)
  .setOptions({
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Longitude',
      viewWindow: {min: -118.870, max: -117.487},
    },
    vAxis: {title: 'VIIRS ???'},
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    pointSize: 0,                // <--- hide the points.
    lineSize: 3                  // <--- show the line.
  });
print(lineChart);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a437359d6fdb2efcaa281b6b86e44885)

[image]

Comment: Awesome tips! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Great job Justin.  Solved my lineChart issue perfectly.